# Grails 3.3 GORM CriteriaBuilder functions on properties

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria, grails-3.3

I'm using Grails 3.3 and GORM CriteriaBuilder for most of my querying these days but I am stuck on how to call functions on properties - for example, calling the hour() function on a Date property.  If I were using where DetachedCriteria I could have something like this:

```
def whereQuery = Student.where {
    hour(registration) = 15
}
```

to find all students who registered between 15:00 and 15:59.

However, if I use a CriteriaBuilder instead, I cannot do this:

```
def c = Student.createCriteria()
def results =  c.list {
    eq 'hour(registration)', 15
}
```

Is there some way to accomplish this in the builder DSL?  I know I can go back to the domain class and define a mapping that extracts the hour from the date field but that seems kind of clumsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `sqlRestriction` a try:

```
def results = Student.withCriteria {
    sqlRestriction 'hour(registration) = 15'
}
```

See `7.5.6. Using SQL Restrictions` in http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#criteria

Comment: Excellent suggestion, injecteer, with a slight modification.  Using PostgreSQL as my back end, rather than using the Hibernate 'hour' function, I had to use this: `sqlRestriction 'extract(hour from registration) = 15'`